# Const vs Static Const

Tags: c, object, memory, static, constants

How does the compiler (e.g. GCC) allocates `const` and `static const` variable, as in, where would it reside? In data memory or program memory?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It depends on your system, and on how you use the variable.  For `static` variables:

**Case 1:** You never use the variable, and the compiler silently discards it.  This cannot happen with `extern` variables.

**Case 2:** You use the variable, but you never take its address.  The compiler converts use of the variable to immediate operands, just as if it were a `#define` or `enum`.  The compiler can still convert `extern` static to immediate operands, but it must still find an address for it anyway.

**Case 3:**  You use the variable and take its address, the compiler is forced to find a place to put it in the object code, exactly as if it were `extern`.

As for "data" versus "program" memory, well, that is very specific to the system you are using.  On my Linux x64/ELF system, it will probably get put in the `.rodata` section, which goes in the same segment as code (`.text`), but a different segment from read-write data sections (`.bss`, `.data`).  My system appears not to create a separate segment for read-only non-executable data.

**Addendum:** Note that the behavior is different in C++.  In C++, a `const` variable has internal linkage by default, so `static const` is redundant and `extern const` is necessary to get a constant with external linkage.

Answer (score 7):

Dietrich has already explained the case of `static` variables well.

For local variables the compiler implementation has several choice on where to allocate a `const` qualified variable for which the address is taken. It may or may not be allocated on the stack or in static memory. This is particularly the case for `const` qualified compound literals. The addresses of two such literals that are locally declared in different scopes may be folded into one and their addresses may compare equal.