# What is the difference between static const and const?

Tags: c, static, constants

What is the difference between `static const` and `const`?
For example:

```
static const int a=5;
const int i=5;
```

Is there any difference between them?
When would you use one over the other?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381088/const-vs-static-const

Comment: Voted to reopen. The "duplicate" is asking an entirely different question, specific to memory usage. This question asks a more general question about the difference.

Comment: I think you ask this question when you don't understand the meaning of **static**. So, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/) explanation might be helpful.

Comment: @Scott please don't use geeksforgeeks for anything C or C++ language related. cppreference is a much more precise resource for C and C++.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The difference is the linkage.

```
// At file scope
static const int a=5;  // internal linkage
const int i=5;         // external linkage
```

If the `i` object is not used outside the translation unit where it is defined, you should declare it with the `static` specifier.

This enables the compiler to (potentially) perform further optimizations and informs the reader that the object is not used outside its translation unit.

Comment: +1 It'd be great if you could also add what it means if those declarations are within a function.

Comment: Are you sure that `const int i = 5;` has external linkage?? In C++ it doesn't...

Comment: @KerrekSB at file-scope, yes. *(C99, 6.2.2p5) "If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external."*

Comment: @KerrekSB: C and C++ are not the same language. In particular, C `const` has nothing to do with C++ `const`.

Comment: Do compilers really optimize based on static? Seems like it's not safe to assume that a static object is not used outside of its translation unit since it can still be passed out by non-static function or pointed to by a non-static global pointer.

Answer (score 145):

`static` determines visibility outside of a function or a variables lifespan inside. So it has nothing to do with `const` per se.

`const` means that you're not changing the value after it has been initialised.

`static` inside a function means the variable will exist before and after the function has executed.

`static` outside of a function means that the scope of the symbol marked `static` is limited to that .c file and cannot be seen outside of it.

Technically (if you want to look this up), `static` is a storage specifier and `const` is a type qualifier.

Comment: My upvote for a more simpler explanation. But you probably want to see @ouah’s explanation and how it could help advanced programmers and teachers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether these definitions are inside of a function or not. The answer for the case *outside* a function is given by ouah, above. *Inside* of a function the effect is different, illustrated by the example below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void my_function() {
  const int foo = rand();         // Perfectly OK!
  static const int bar = rand();  // Compile time error.
}
```

If you want a local variable to be "really constant," you have to define it not just "const" but "static const".

Comment: It perfectly compiles for me... But I know it's stupid to have a static const variable in this case.

Comment: @DrumM it's not stupid. In the case of `foo` the variable is re-initialised every time `my_function()` is called, resulting in a different random value being assigned. In the case of `bar` the variable initialised only once, the first time `my_function()` is called resulting in the same value being assigned for the lifetime of the program. Hence static storage duration.

Comment: Actually, on further reflection, it depends on if we're using C or C++. The question is tagged C, in which case we get a compile error for the assignment of `bar` due to `rand()` not being a compile-time constant.

Comment: @nibot can you clarify what you mean by "the effect is different" and "really constant" with reference to storage specification and type qualification?

Answer (score 0):

```
const int i=5;
```

`i` value you can modify by using a pointer if `i` is defined and declared locally,
if it is `static const int a=5;`  or `const int i=5;` globally , you can not modify since it is stored in RO memory in Data Segment.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
   //const int  a=10;              /* can not modify */
   int main(void) {
   // your code goes here

   //static const int const a=10;   /* can not modify */
   const int  a=10; 
   int *const ptr=&a;
   *ptr=18;
   printf("The val a is %d",a);
   return 0;
}
```